# Make scrollbar "thumb" thinner than "track" +Box-shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello people**, i am trying to make the thumb's width thinner than the tack's width so that i can have a shadow effect on the thumb *( such as it will look like the thumb-bar is floating on top of the track-bar)*.

Does anyone have any idea or if it is possible in the first place?

Thanks in Advance,
George.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit)

Comment: @Vishnu i've looked at this site before, i just can't find out how... although thanks (:

Comment: add the lines to your css `::-webkit-scrollbar-track : { box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); width: 20px } `

Comment: @Vishnu **first** of all i dont want inset shadows and **Second** of all i want them on the thumb not on the track _( thats my point :P)_

Comment: This is definitely possible...

Comment: @Toby56 do you have any idea how...?

Comment: I think it may only be possible if you forget the shadow and give it a border the same color as the track

Comment: Or you do something fancy with multiple shadows

Comment: @Toby56 i have already tried that trick with the border before but thanks for suggesting

Comment: if i could have inset box-shadow expanding from the center would also help me... checking out linear-gradient right now and etc...

Comment: I think I did it!

Comment: :D :D :D :D ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work!

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 2000px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px white, inset 0 0 0 4px black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Should look like this:

[image: scrollbar]

You can tinker around with it, but it goes a bit yuck if you add rounded corners!

Now it isn't so bad:

[image: scrollbar2]

Comment: Thats amazing, Thanks you! although could we find out any way to fix it for the rounded corners too?

Comment: I'm glad you like it. I'm still trying to figure out how I did it, my brain isn't working very well tonight. I don't think there is any way to fix the rounded corner unfortunately.

Comment: Here is a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-microservice-xtdt8

Comment: I have lessened the weird things with the rounded corners so you probably won't notice.

Comment: it's funny that this is happening with the lines but anyways i am pretty happy with the answer for now :D (although i think it could be possible using radial-gradient somehow too)

Comment: Well, have fun!