# How to add box-shadow to scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to add box-shadow to scrollbar that is not inset? This works for me but I need it to be outside not inside and when I remove `inset` it doesn't work at all.

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

**Edit**

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666290/make-scrollbar-thumb-thinner-than-track-box-shadow

Comment: thanks for that but it isn't what I need, I need the track to have outside box shadow not the thumb

Comment: I added edit with preview of what I need

Answer (score 1):

for chrome you have to trick somehow and draw the outset dark shadow from a light shadow inset and reduce the thumb with a transparent border. background can then redrawn via gradients and background-size:

that would only work for chrome.

possible example you can inspire yourself from: http://jsfiddle.net/znyb17um/

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 28px;
  margin:0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 14px 18px, white 5px, transparent 7px) no-repeat, radial-gradient(circle at 14px calc(100% - 18px), white 5px, transparent 7px) no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) center no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 12px white;
  background-size: auto, auto, calc(100% - 16px) calc(100% - 40px);
  margin:0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #F6D87E;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```